# Cant connect Oneplus 2 to Mac via USB

Tags: root-access, usb-debugging, oneplus-two

Ok, I have Oneplus Two, with the latest OxygenOS 3.0.2 (android 6.0.1), not rooted.
First sad thing is that there is no option in "Developer Options" to do "ADB over network", seems like developers removed it, which is really frustrating for me, because I have a lot of trouble connecting the phone to my Mac.

By lot of troubles I mean I cannot do it. I tried everything that google offered, hell I spend whole day trying to figure it out and nothing.
Literally nothing happens when I plug in the phone to Mac (phone is charging).

system.log dump: `kernel[0]: 006676.874534 HS01@14100000: AppleUSB20XHCIPort::resetAndCreateDevice: failed to create device, disabling port`

`adb devices` yields empty list of devices, android studio same.

I checked my `adb_usb.ini`, it cotains this id 0x2a70.
I can't even root my phone to use 3rd party adb over wifi to start developing.

Anyway I can get the usb connection to work with my Mac?

Comment: Did you make it working? I also have OnePlus 2 (OxygenOS 3.6.0), Android version 6.0.1. I have enabled Developer Options and also enabled "USB Debugging" in the phone. Whenever I connect my phone (using original USB cable) to my Macbook, it just charges and shows nothing about debugging? Any clues?

Comment: No, I end up drowning my phone and bought OP5

Answer (score 0):

To enable Developer mode, go to *Settings*, then *About phone* and click on *Kernel* or *Build number* several times until you will become a developer.

Now you should have *OnePlus Drivers* mounted where you can find Mac app for file transfers and shell script for ADB configuration.

If you still having trouble connecting via USB, try to use the original cable.